# New to BibTeX and APA syle: What do I do?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apacite

I'm completely lost. I use LaTeX, but not competently. I want to do a bibliography and in-text citations in APA style.

I downloaded JabRef and did a test entry. Then I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{testname}

\end{document}
```

...where `testname` is the name of my BibTeX file. My reference does not appear when I do this, though it does say "reference." I'm using TeXstudio, in case anyone is interested.

So, what do I do? Can someone explain to me in super simple terms how to get my entries from JabRef into an APA-style bibliography/in-text citations in TeXstudio?

Comment: See also [How to compile bibtex with TeXstudio?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/156205)

Comment: Your code features no citation commands

Comment: @AlanMunn - The OP hasn't indicated that he/she is getting question marks where the citation call-out commands are placed. Instead, the OP reports getting the header "Reference[s]" but, if I understand the posting correctly, no formatted bib entries. To me, that sounds like the OP (a) hasn't even run BibTeX and (b) may be lacking any `\cite`-like instructions.

Comment: Please advise as to whether you've run BibTeX at all. If you did, do you get any error or warning messages? If yes, what do the messages say? Does the body of your document contain any `\cite`-like commands? If yes, what is displayed where the citation call-outs should inserted?